# Web Analytics Report for a Subsite

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I need to show to the Subsite owners the visitors of their site with the specific time. I know about the Site Analytics Report but it just gives an overview of top visitors and top sites/pages. Can we make changes to it and display the users with the specific time when they visited the site.

I know about Audit Reports but again they can be turned on only for a site collection level and I do not want that.

I would really appreciate if we can find a solution without any custom code as I don't want to get into that.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news web analytics in SharePoint 2013/2016 offer less what we have in SharePoint 2010. In SharePoint 2013/16 you will get only top thing, they called it popularity trend. You can get this for single item, library or subsite. But i know this will not full fill you requirement.

[Check this workaround, mentioned last part of the blog](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/new-sharepoint-2013-analytics)

In this situation you need the 3rd party tools.[CardioLog Analytics](http://www.intlock.com/products/sharepoint-office365-analytics/adaptors/reporting-for-sharepoint-2013/) or [Webtrends](https://www.webtrends.com/)

You can try free tool from codeplex for google analytics [Google Analytics SharePoint 2013 / Office 365](https://googleanalytics365.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The Analytics generate two reports that are based on usage event types:

**Popularity Trends** shows usage event statistics for a site collection, a site, or an individual item in a library or list.

**Most Popular Items** shows usage event statistics for all items in a library or list.

The reports are broken down per usage event type. The default usage event types are as follows:

**Views**. The number of views for a single item, page or document.

**Recommendations Displayed**. The number of times a single item, page or document was displayed as a recommendation.

**Recommendations Clicked**. The number of times s single item, page or document was clicked when it was displayed as a recommendation.

You can also add any custom usage event types.

For more information about the Analytics Processing Component and usage events, see [Overview of analytics processing in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/jj219554.aspx). For information about search reports — for example, Number of Queries or Top Queries by Day — see [Usage reports](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/132283-how-to-find-most-visited-sites-with-number-of-view-counts-in-sharepoint-2013)

Hope this helps!